# Htaccess not working for my domain sub folders alone

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used so many codes to redirect my sub folder url, but not working.

```
From :: http://www.mydomain.com/doctor/searchresult.php?txtcity=Chennai&txtarea=Annanagar

To  :: http://www.mydomain.com/doctor/Chennai/Annanagar
```

The used htaccess codes are given below

```
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/searchresult$ /doctor/searchresult.php?txtcity=$1&txtarea=$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/doctor/$  searchresult.php?txtcity=$1&txtarea=$2

RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /doctor/searchDocResult.php?selFindDocCity=$1&txtFindDocAreaRzip=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The first rule is an external redirect (meaning the `?txtcity` variant is publicly visible). The rules reference matches `$1` and `$2`, but only have one capturing group each. And what does `searchDocResult.php` do in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just trying to redirect the first URL to the second listed URL, this is works on my server.

One thing to note is that the order they are listed does make a difference. The most specific need to be listed first, such that all the txtarea's within a txt city must be listed first per my example below.

Good luck let me know how it works out for you.

Tim

Tim@mpact-media.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} searchresult\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} txtarea=Annanagar
RewriteRule .* doctor/Chennai/Annanagar/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} searchresult\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} txtcity=Chennai
RewriteRule .* doctor/Chennai/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make any `.htaccess` work, you need to do two things.

First thing is to enable it, in the Apache config file, inside the `<Directory>` directive that matches your path, the `AllowOverride`. For instance:

```
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

This will allow to override at the "/" (webroot) with the things specified in the `.htaccess` file. Here's the [complete spec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) for `AllowOverride` directive.

Second thing will be to place inside the `.htaccess` any valid directive.

Remember that the `RewriteCond` rules stack up eachother, until you put a `RewriteRule` directive. This is how you will be able to make more complex rules. You'll find a nice guide for this [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).